# FluentWait timesout before set timeout is reached

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to achieve two fluent waits for two different elements after each other the landing time differs depending on server demand. Removing the second fluent wait `foo2` makes the code work as expected. But when adding the second the first one times out after 1 second with element not visible exception thrown.

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
        .withTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/userdb']"));
    }
});

foo.click();

WebElement foo2 = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/itemdb']"));
    }
});

foo2.click();
```

Comment: You noticed it yourself, the formatting renders your question completely unreadable. Please keep in mind that humans have to parse this text and take the time to help them to figure out what you might mean with minimal effort (they are trying to help you for free!!). Please get back to some Desktop and format the code in a decent manner.

Comment: @Marco thanks for editing for me.

Comment: You will probably need two different `wait`s here. I'm not sure you can reuse them like that.

Comment: I've tired that by calling the second wait 'wait2 with foo2 referencing that which as they're two different objects should work but the first foo1 timeouts after 1 second not the preset 90.